# Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, terminal, command-line

does anyone know? why is this error:

PS D:\Andnata77\Belajar\FLUTTER\flutter_application_1> flutter pub get
Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

- flutter pub get
- 

At line:1 char:1

- flutter pub get
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do ? do you try copy files from project to another project ? just clone it from github or just copy lib file not other ones. try this

1. Delete **.packages**
2. Delete **pubspec.lock**
3. flutter **clean**
4. Flutter **pub get**
5. flutter **pub Upgrade**
6. Flutter **Upgrade**

Comment: i use eset security, is it because of that?

Comment: i am creating json.php, then linked with pubspec.yaml,
i added on dependecies:
 sdk: flutter
http: ^0.13.1,
then to the terminal flutter pub get